# django added at end of app names automatically

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django but have encountered a problem while adding apps to Installed apps in settings.py
I added 'polls' app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

but an error has occurred which says

```
ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; 'polls.apps' is not a package
```

when I write only 'polls' instead of 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
the following error occurs `ImportError: No module named 'pollsdjango'

the name of app I am trying to import is 'polls'

Comment: You are missing a comma after `PollsConfig'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after `PollsConfig'`

Try this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```